# Loading raster in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I am trying to load raster in PostGIS from my Windows cmd using:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>raster2pgsql.exe -s 4326 -I -C -M "D:\9.Taji\data\1_Admin Boundary-20200211T030329Z-001\check\raster\road_raster.tif" -F -T 100x100 public.road  | psql -d postgres -U postgres -p 5432
```

But every time I run I get this error:

> BEGIN ERROR:  tablespace "100x100" does not exist ERROR:  current
>   transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction
>   block ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until
>   end of transaction block ERROR:  current transaction is aborted,
>   commands ignored until end of transaction block ERROR:  current
>   transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction
>   block ROLLBACK ERROR:  relation "public.road" does not exist

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Loading user data with the `postgres` login is an opportunity to damage your database instance. You should always create lesser privileged logins to create and manage user data.

Answer (score 2):

Read again the documentation https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html, especially at these points:

> **-T tablespace**
>
> Specify the tablespace for the new table. Note that indices (including
>   the primary key) will still use the default tablespace unless the -X
>   flag is also used.
>
> **-t TILE_SIZE**
>
> Cut raster into tiles to be inserted one per table row. TILE_SIZE is
>   expressed as WIDTHxHEIGHT or set to the value "auto" to allow the
>   loader to compute an appropriate tile size using the first raster and
>   applied to all rasters.